# Is there any way to easily change proxy in macOS without going to System preferences > Network > advanced > proxy > etc

Tags: macos, proxy

I daily need to switch proxies in macOS and going every time to System Preferences > Network > advanced > proxies > enable HTTP proxy and secure web proxy, is really frustrating.

Is there any way or app that acts similar(on macos) to foxyproxy in browsers?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think the most *macOS* way is to use Locations:

1. Go to System Preferences > Network,
2. Select "Location" dropdown menu,
3. Select "Edit Locations",

[image]

4. Choose Duplicate location and make a copy from your default Automatic:

[image]

Select a name corresponding to your Proxy name.

5. Switch to new location and edit the proxy under *Advanced*

[image]

6. Once all Locations are added, feel free to use them from  menu:

[image]

Comment: Why the negative vote? This is an excellent answer. +1

Comment: little different in Sonoma, but Perfect solution.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible by executing the following CLI

```
$ networksetup -setwebproxy "Wi-Fi" 127.0.0.1 9090 && networksetup -setsecurewebproxy "Wi-Fi" 127.0.0.1 9090
```

Assume that 127.0.0.1 and 9090 is the IP and port you need to Proxy

You can disable HTTP Proxy by

```
$ networksetup -setwebproxystate "Wi-Fi" off && networksetup -setsecurewebproxystate "Wi-Fi" off
```